# Find the maximum possible summation of differences of consecutive elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

> Array A contains the elements, **A1,A2...AN.** And array B contains the elements, **B1,B2...BN**.     There is a relationship between **Ai and Bi, for 1 = i = N, i.e., 
>   any element Ai lies between 1 and Bi**.

Let the cost S of an array A be defined as:

[image: Cost of the array S]

You have to print the largest possible value of S.
The Link to the problem is [Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-cost)

**Example**:
`size of array`:5
`array`: 10 1 10 1 10
`output` : 36 `(since the max value can be derived as |10 - 1| + |1 - 10| + |10 - 1| + |1 - 10|)`

**Approach** :
The only approach i could think of was brute force. I thought i would make a overlapping recursive equation so that i could memoize it, but was not able to.

**CODE** :

```java
public static void func(int pos,int[] arr,int[] aux,int n)
    {
        /*
         * pos is current index in the arr
         * arr is array
         * aux is temp array which will store one possible combination.
         * n is size of the array.
         * */



        //if reached at the end, check the summation of differences
        if(pos == n)
        {
            long sum = 0;
            for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
            {
                //System.out.print("i = " + i + ", arr[i] = " + aux[i] + " ");
                sum += Math.abs(aux[i] - aux[i - 1]);
            }
            //System.out.println();
            //System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
            if(sum > max)
            {
                max = sum;
            }
            return;
        }

        //else try every combination possible.
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= arr[pos] ; i++)
        {
            aux[pos] = i;
            func(pos + 1,arr,aux,n);
        }
}
```

**NOTE**:
The complexity of this is O(n*2^n)

Comment: You can reorder elements so that S has the biggest possible value? The explanation to the linked problem mentions that, but it's not explicitly stated anywhere.

Comment: From your problem statement, I don't understand the relevance of the B array, and I don't understand what variables you need to maximize S over.

Comment: @PiotrKocia . i dont think you will get the correct answer if you reorder the elements.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b I have given the link to the problem.

Comment: Oh, he gave a link to the problem.  The idea is, chose any values for A_i, subject to the constraints given in the B_i.

Comment: Then the algorithm is just `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is no reason that `a[i]` should be equal to any number besides `1` and `b[i]`. Realizing that we can write down a simple recurrence:

```
fmax(1) = fone(1) = 0
fmax(i) = max(fone(i-1) + b[i] - 1, fmax(i-1) + abs(b[i]-b[i-1]))
fone(i) = max(fone(i-1), fmax(i-1) + b[i-1] - 1)

answer = max(fmax(N), fone(N))
```

Where `fmax(i)` is a maximal sum for `a[1..i]` elements that end with `b[i]`, `fone(i)` is a maximal sum for `a[1..i]` elements that end with `1`.

With dynamic programming approach, the complexity is `O(N)`.

Comment: Memoization will give the best solution. This answer should be accepted.

Comment: @DAle . if you could help me understand,  how did you realize two function definitions were needed for this?

Comment: @Manya Don't you understand the formulas or why there are two of them?

Comment: @DAle i did understand the formulas once you gave them. but i didnt understand the thought process behind it. Mostly i have used DP where with only one function definition i have solved the problem.

Comment: @DAle. just one question. instead of taking another function. can we include one more variable like flag whose value can be binary(1 or 0) to tell whether the ith elementh will be 1 or b[i]. ?

Comment: @Manya, two functions here are for simplicity, we could consider one function `f(i, b)` where `b = 0` when `a[i] = 1` and `b = 1` when `a[i] = b[i]`. We have a two-dimensional space state in the problem `(length, isOne)`, but `isOne` - is a boolean value, so I used one function for every value.

Comment: @DAle. yeah i think i got it now. in my last comment i was trying to convey that only. thanks for patience and answer.